GitLab CI/CD: How to run a partial pipeline using a job from previous run?
For learning purposes, I have created the following .gitlab-ci.yml
stages:
  - stage1
  - stage2

job1:
  image: alpine:3.20.0
  stage: stage1
  script:
    - pwd
    - ls
    - test -f dummyfile

job2:
  image: alpine:3.20.0
  stage: stage2
  script:
    - pwd
    - ls
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)$/

This works as expected - kind of. When I push a commit, a pipeline is started, containing job1. If I tag that same commit and push it to origin, another pipeline is created, now containing two jobs.
When I write "kind of", I mean that if both pipelines work on the same commit, why, after tagging the commit, job1 from first pipeline is not reused in the second pipeline? In both pipelines job1 did the same thing on the same commit. Is there any configuration option in GitLab to allow inter-pipeline job sharing for the same commit?
I know that I can apply specific rules: for every job, but what I want to achieve is when the job1 fails in the first pipeline, job2 should also fail in the second pipeline / not run at all. With rules: it cannot be accomplished AFAIK, because pipelines are independent.
Caching the result of the first job kind of resolves the problem, but the job itself still needs to run and requires extra logic.
